# How to push NavigationController on Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

With Xcode 4.1, I used to push a Navigation Controller using the following code:

```
-(IBAction)goClasse1:(id)sender{

        Classe1Chamada *goCL1 = [[Classe1Chamada alloc] initWithNibName:@"Classe1Chamada" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:goCL1 animated:YES];
    [goCL1];

}
```

But now I updated to Xcode 4.2, this code just doesn't work.  Why?  How can I fix it?

Comment: does nothing happen?  do you get an error?

Comment: what is `[goCL1];`? I think it should be `[goCL1 release];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use it like this:

```
-(IBAction)goClasse1:(id)sender{

        Classe1Chamada *goCL1 = [[Classe1Chamada alloc] initWithNibName:@"Classe1Chamada" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:goCL1 animated:YES];
    [goCL1 release];

}
```

and you don't need to initialize or delegate navigation controller in all your view controllers: it is already initialized in ViewController class.